# JWPlayer 6 caption MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jwplayer, closed-captions

My application is MVC5, I have upgraded JWPlayer from 5.10 to 6.9.  The caption does not working, here is my script:

```
  jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "../Video/when.mp4",
            image: "../Content/images/when.png",
            tracks: [{
                file: '../Video/when.dfxp',
                label: "English",
                kind: "captions",
                "default": true
            },{
                file: '../Video/when.srt',
                kind: "captions",
                label: "French"
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Same srt was working with version 5.10.  Converted the srt file to vtt and dfxp, tested on IE, Chrome, and FireFox; none worked.

Comment: According to http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407438-adding-closed-captions, your code suppose to work. please provide link where you run your player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok.

In your site  `www.scanitfirst.com` link to caption files are broken (404 not found)

```
http://www.scanitfirst.com/Video/when.dfxp //404
http://www.scanitfirst.com/Video/when.srt  //404
```

If you will fix this, your caption should work as expected

Comment: Thank you Ben, however the files are there; I also tried it on localhost.

Comment: I get 404 when opening links

Comment: Ben, the problem was MIME type, I had to add the following to web.config:    <mimeMap fileExtension=".srt" mimeType="text/plain" />.  It works now, thank you for leading me to the cause of the problem.